# Php create namespace path from $_GET[] elements and use it

Tags: php, namespaces, get

i want from url like this: example.com/?module=index&controller=index&action=hello
to get the values by $_GET[] and then create namespace path like application\modules\index\controllers\IndexController and then

```
use application\modules\index\controllers\IndexController as IndexController;
$IndexController = new IndexController;
$IndexController->hello();
```

for example, but when i try to create the path in random ways -> error and .. i don't know how to do it please help!

Comment: Could you possibly show what you have tried? For some examples of this, you might consider looking at the Symfony2 or Zend Framework *routing* component

Comment: i tried to replace names of the module and controller by $_GET['module'] and controller and syntax error appear, then i tried to put all the path in string but then i type use $namespacePath ... same shit..

Comment: Show how you are trying to create this namespace path. Also you can't use variables in `use` statement, you have to use fully namespaced class name in variable when creating new instance;

Comment: just to create instance from fully namespaces class name in variable? without use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment: you can't use variables in use statement, you have to use fully namespaced class name in variable when creating new instance.

So it would look like this:

```
$module = $_GET['module'];
$ctrl = $_GET['controller'];
//Remember to use double backslashes in strings
$class = "application\\modules\\{$module}\\controllers\\{$ctrl}Controller";

$controller = new $class;
$controller->{$action}();
```

Answer (score 0):

More code would be useful but does this help?

```
namespace Foobar;

class Foo {
    static public function test() {
        echo "Hello";
    }
}

call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo::'.$_GET['action']); 
// or
call_user_func(array(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo', $_GET['action']));
```